# Handlebar expression doesn't get parsed

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, express-handlebars

On the pointed line I'm using the extension handlebars of HTML for take the ID of BBDD of mongo but the problem is that the "href" doesn't detect the `{{_id}}`

```html
<div class="row">
    {{#each notes}}
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
               <h4 class="card-title d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            {{ title }} <a href="/notes/{{_id}}/edit"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                    <!--en el href hacemos referencia
                    a la ubicacion mas el id con handlebars-->
               </h4>
               <p>{{ Description  }}</p>
               <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-sm">
                   Delete
               </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{else}}
    <div class="card mx-auto">
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="lead">no existen notas aun</p>
            <a href="/notes/add" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
                Create one
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: Andreas is right for the title. next, you need to show some more code and explain what you want to achieve in a global manner.

Comment: You might find the Spanish version of Stack Overflow useful: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You may want to give more details about what you have in JavaScript. Perhaps _id isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

on the line  {{ title }} , the {{_id}} is not detected for MONGO, i need use this for modify the document in the database